# In Cocos2d-x 3.2(Lua), how to detect if point is in a rect?

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

Here is event handle function, `self` is a `cc.Node`, `self.bg` is a `cc.Sprite`

```
local function onTouchEnded(touch, event)
        local location = touch:getLocation()
        local size = self.bg:getContentSize() 
        local rect = cc.rect(self:getPositionX(),self:getPositionY(),size.width,size.height)

end
```

How to compare `location` and `rect` to check if this sprite is click, I have read this document,
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/d4/d8a/classcocos2d_1_1_rect.html#a011e04551ca371f8a99d2a3f47cd499e

seems `cc.rect` don't have `containsPoint` function, is there other way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if location.x > rect.x and location.x < rect.x + rect.width and
   location.y > rect.y and location.y < rect.y + rect.height then
   -- location is in rect, do your stuff
end
```